# Android - Saved image in external storage doesn't appear in gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage, android-internal-storage

I'm trying to copy images from internal to external storage by this method:

```
private val externalStorage = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

override fun savePhotoToExternalStorage(file: File) {
    val toFile = File(externalStorage, file.name)
    file.copyTo(toFile, true)
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(toFile.path), null, null)
}
```

I see that image is saving in path **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/pl.renesans.renesans/files/Pictures/image.jpg** and I can find it in my phone's files, but it doesn't appear in gallery. What am I doing wrong? I'm using wrong path to save this image or I'm using MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() in wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MediaStore does not collect info about files in app specific folders.

Hence no info from `getExternalFilesdir()`.

Gallery apps rely on the MediaStore.

On Android below Q you can use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` and such.

Or `Environment.getExternalPublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`.

Comment: And what can I use on Android 10?

Comment: If you add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`  to application tag in manifest file you can continue to use the external storage stuff in Android Q too. But in general you should directly store to MediaStore then.

Comment: @Oktawian did you find the solution ?